# Integration of Ignition to ROS2 galactic

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using ROS 2 Galactic Geochelone on a Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS os and was trying to Integrate ROS2 with Ignition and required a ros_ign_bridge, I was inquiring if there are binaries available for ROS2 galactic or are they only available for foxy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379968/integration-of-ignition-to-ros2-galactic/) by [Overlord](https://answers.ros.org/users/75775/overlord/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Binaries are available:

```
sudo apt install ros-galactic-ros-ign-bridge
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.ros.org/users/4654/chapulina/) with karma: 366 on 2021-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0